# Working on project Web + Android + Raspberry Pi (with its GPS module)

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, gps, raspberry-pi

Im working on a project where I uses Raspberry Pi with the itead GPS (Add-on 2.0) which uploads the GPS location information to a database periodically. Website (with Google Maps API) will be used for configuration and can access the information from the database. The last module is the android app which also uses that database to exchange the information.
So the GPS location info goes to the database, web and android accesses the database.

What technology, framework and language should be used for website designing?
What database should I use?

Comment: It really depends on your background knowledge, Last year i worked for a similiar project and i used J2ee for my website and Relational Databases. and to communicate between my android device and my database i used a web service . I advice you to do more research in advance

Comment: Firstly, Your comment n suggestion is very appreciated. I need some guideline to go through adopting things. I worked on ASP.NET MVC. If you can tell me what kind of web service will be suitable for this project ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have done a web based application with Google maps Api for web (JavaScript), JavaScript , php, MYSQL  and XML.
JavaScript was used for the logic part  , Google Maps Api to draw the map , add markers and such.php to send /receive data , XML as an interface to/from php and to/from JavaScript.